# How to validate string using regex in html using pattern field in textbox?

Tags: html, regex, forms

I want to validate this string `"B3:D7,0 H3:J7,0 B9:L27,1 B29:L48,2 B50:L56,2"` using pattern but it doesn't match. I don't know what error there is in the regex string.

I used `pattern="[A-Z][0-99]+:[A-Z][0-99]+,[0-9]+"` inside textfield in html

Comment: FYI, `[0-99]` is the same as `[0-9]`.

Comment: If you're new to regex, you can take a look at https://regexr.com/ where you can paste your regular expression and it will explain to you in English what it's trying to match.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot `(` and `)+` around your pattern:

```txt
pattern="([A-Z][0-9]+:[A-Z][0-9]+,[0-9]+)+"
```

or

```txt
pattern="([A-Z][0-9]+:[A-Z][0-9]+,[0-9])+"
```

if the last digit may occour only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below pattern:

```
([A-Z][0-9]+\:[A-Z][0-9]+,[0-9]\s?){5}
```

Answer (score 0):

To match a digit 0-9 you can use `[0-9]` or `\d`

Assuming you don't want spaces at the start and at the end, you can repeat the pattern 1 or more times preceded by a space.

```
^[A-Z]\d+:[A-Z]\d+,\d+(?: [A-Z]\d+:[A-Z]\d+,\d+)+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]\d+:[A-Z]\d+,\d+` Match `:` between a char A-Z and 1+ digits followed by `,` and 1+ digits
- `(?: [A-Z]\d+:[A-Z]\d+,\d+)+` Repeat 1+ times the same pattern with a space preceded.
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GA3KrV/1)

Using the pattern attribute, you [can omit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern#constraint_validation) the start and end anchors as they are already implied.

```
pattern="[A-Z]\d+:[A-Z]\d+,\d+(?: [A-Z]\d+:[A-Z]\d+,\d+)+"
```

**Note** that if you want to match a digit 1-99 you can use `[1-9]\d?`

Comment: Works for "B3:D7,0 H3:J7,0 B9:L27,1 B29:L48,2 B50:L56,2" but doesn't work for string like "A1:X30,2"

Comment: @HemilShah Then you can use `^[A-Z]\d+:[A-Z]\d+,\d+(?: [A-Z]\d+:[A-Z]\d+,\d+)*$` with `*` as a quantifier for 0 or more times. See https://regex101.com/r/sMjQWJ/1